# Create a new DataFrame adding each key from a column dict as header

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a DataFrame which contains a certain column with Dictionaries.

I want to add a new header in the DataFrame for each key found on each element in the column that contains dicts, each new value assigned to those new cells should correspond to `None` if that element doesn't contain that header key and the respective key value otherwise.

Here's the data for testing and visualizing what I'm saying:

Importing dependencies:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Creating a dictionary that contains a inner dictionary list:

```
data = {'string_info': ['User1', 'User2', 'User3'],
        'dict_info': [{'elm1': 'attr5', 'elm2': 'attr9', 'elm3': 'attr33'},
                 {'elm5': 'attr31', 'elm7': 'attr13'},
                 {'elm5': 'attr28', 'elm1': 'attr23', 'elm2': 'attr33','elm6': 'attr33'}],
        'int_info': [4, 24, 31],}
```

Creating an appropriate initial DataFrame for testing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

Manually stating what I want as output:

```
data2 = {'string_info': ['User1', 'User2', 'User3'],
        'elm1': ['attr5',None,'attr23'],
        'elm2': ['attr9',None,'attr33'],
        'elm3': ['attr33',None,None],
        'elm4': [None,None,None],
        'elm5': [None,'attr31',None],
        'elm6': [None,None,'attr33'],
        'elm7': [None,None,'attr13'],
        'int_info': [4, 24, 31]}
```

The desired output would be:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
df2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `DataFrame` constructor for replace `dict` to columns:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df.dict_info.values.tolist()))
     elm1    elm2    elm3    elm5    elm6    elm7
0   attr5   attr9  attr33     NaN     NaN     NaN
1     NaN     NaN     NaN  attr31     NaN  attr13
2  attr23  attr33     NaN  attr28  attr33     NaN

print (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.dict_info.values.tolist()),
                  df[['int_info','string_info']]], axis=1))
     elm1    elm2    elm3    elm5    elm6    elm7  int_info string_info
0   attr5   attr9  attr33     NaN     NaN     NaN         4       User1
1     NaN     NaN     NaN  attr31     NaN  attr13        24       User2
2  attr23  attr33     NaN  attr28  attr33     NaN        31       User3
```

And if need `None`s add [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
print (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.dict_info.values.tolist()).replace({np.nan:None}), 
                  df[['int_info','string_info']]], axis=1))
     elm1    elm2    elm3    elm5    elm6    elm7  int_info string_info
0   attr5   attr9  attr33    None    None    None         4       User1
1    None    None    None  attr31    None  attr13        24       User2
2  attr23  attr33    None  attr28  attr33    None        31       User3
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I'm definitely checking out more about pd.concat, thanks!